# Can not install substrate on emulator

Tags: android-sdk

I'm trying to install cydia substrate on emulator, when I try to `link substrate files` I got multiple errors,

Then I replaced `/system/xbin/su` with a suid-ed `/system/bin/sh` file and disabled SELinux with setenforce command.

But I still got this:

[image]

Anyone know what should I do? With `adb shell` I can get root but I don't know what script to run ....